# iPhone : How to obtain the number of lines entered in textView without consideration of width

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview, ios-4.2

In my iPhone app, I have a textview where in the user will input multi-line data.

Now I need a solution where I can get the number of lines.

I need a solution which does not have consideration of width.

I need only number of lines entered by user in textView.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said "without consideration of width" and not "without consideration of height", this is how you do it:

```
int numberOfLines = yourUITextView.contentSize.height / yourUITextView.font.lineHeight
```

The UIFont property `lineHeight` is new from iOS4.0, for older versions use `leading` property.

Edit,

this answer applies to text views where there have been automatically inserted line breaks (i.e. the line got to long), if you only want to know the number of manually inserted line breaks, Terentes answer would do it.

To count manually inserted line breaks, this hack should do it:

```
int numberOfManuallyBreaks = [[yourUITextView componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count];
```

Comment: Cant you directly use yourUITestView.font.lineheight?

Comment: @Aditya , that only gives you the height of one line.

Comment: Ok I will try that out and get back to you. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Thanks a lot Bjorn. Your solution works well. Very simple and effective solution. Thanks a lot.. I have been searching for a solution for a while now. :) One Vote Up :)

Answer (score 0):

By line you mean when user press the return key on the key board? If so count the \n in it.
Hope that helps.

```
NSArray *arrayWithLines = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"Number of Lines:%@",[arrayWithLines count]);
```

Comment: but how can I do that? When I see the code it doesnot show any \n in there. How to do that? Can you please give some small code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fetching the number of lines by using the numberOfLines property of TextView.

Comment: And where do you find this property? It's not available for UITextView.

Comment: I didnt find number of lines property in textView Aditya. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Parth BJorn's answer is corect